# laravel 5.6 give white page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

my web site is https://antilicense.com/
and I give a white page

PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '.../vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear') in .../vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

my error log:

```
[06-Mar-2018 10:31:34 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(/home/antilic1/public_html/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/antilic1/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
[06-Mar-2018 10:31:34 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/antilic1/public_html/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear') in /home/antilic1/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
[06-Mar-2018 10:31:53 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(/home/antilic1/public_html/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/antilic1/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
[06-Mar-2018 10:31:53 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/antilic1/public_html/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear') in /home/antilic1/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
[06-Mar-2018 10:35:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(/home/antilic1/public_html/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/antilic1/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[06-Mar-2018 10:35:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/antilic1/public_html/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear') in /home/antilic1/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[06-Mar-2018 10:35:49 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem' not found in /home/antilic1/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:175
Stack trace:
#0 /home/antilic1/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(144): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->registerBaseBindings()
#1 /home/antilic1/public_html/bootstrap/app.php(15): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->__construct('/home/antilic1/...')
#2 /home/antilic1/public_html/public/index.php(38): require_once('/home/antilic1/...')
#3 {main}
  thrown in /home/antilic1/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php on line 175
[06-Mar-2018 10:35:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(/home/antilic1/public_html/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/antilic1/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[06-Mar-2018 10:35:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/antilic1/public_html/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear') in /home/antilic1/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[06-Mar-2018 10:35:50 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem' not found in /home/antilic1/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:175
Stack trace:
```

when I unzip files all things is fine
but after few minutes I see white page...

I try:

```
php artisan key:generate 
composer update --no-scripts  
composer update
composer install
composer dump-autoload
```

but I still have problem
please help me. tnx.

---

### note1: I upgraded my laravel 5.5 to 5.6

### note2: It works on local host fine... but when I move it to server I see error log

### this is my php info https://antilicense.com/info.php

Comment: Did you set permissions? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation#configuration -> Directory Permissions

Comment: check if your server is VPS or not

Comment: This could be throwing numerous errors.. Generally start with `php artisan key:gen` then `chmod -R 777 storage/*` and reload the page.

Comment: Also if you have upgraded locally and not server side you need to run: `composer require fideloper/proxy` otherwise it'll throw an array error

Comment: @raskul, I see the error has now been repaired. Can you confirm what fixed it.

Comment: in laravel 5.5 and 5.6 antivirus remove filesystem's files...in shared host

Answer (score 0):

It seems the vendor files are not in the system. Can you do `composer update` and see ?

Also make sure to set the file folder permission properly. Change all the directories to 755 and all the files to 644.

To change all the directories to 755 (drwxr-xr-x):

```
find /home/antilic1/public_html -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

To change all the files to 644 (-rw-r--r--):

```
find /home/antilic1/public_html -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must remove vendor directory in your shared host and run below code in your local project:

```
composer dumpautoload
```

and copy vendor directory from local project to shared host.